# OpenGL ES Drawing Transparent Artifacts

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I am attempting to draw an OBJ file to the screen in an iOS app using [this](https://github.com/nicklockwood/GLView) library. The OBJ file is supposed to be a solid 3D model of teeth, as shown below, but when rendered in the iOS app, it shows up very grainy, and transparent, as shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDOqv.png). How can I draw the surface a uniform, opaque color?

I am using a solid-white image file as the texture, and have not otherwise modified the default settings.

[image: Solid 3D model, shown properly]

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Grainy" just looks like you are rendering multiple layers of triangles with blending enabled, and some triangles are being dropped for some reason so those areas are lighter than their neighbours. Hard to tell why without looking at the model (could be the facing test, or the depth test with very out-of-order triangle streams). In general try disabling the facing test, enabling the depth test, and disabling blending.

Comment: @solidpixel disabling blending worked! However this also removed my texture from the render. Is there a way to configure the blending so as to include my texture without the transparency? Perhaps something with the glBlendFunc?

Comment: Blending and texturing are totally independent - one doesn't impact the other. Are you sure the texturing ever worked on the device?

Comment: Ah ok. It seems texturing is working after all. http://imgur.com/a/lgFJ9 the top shows with blending disabled and the bottom with blending enabled, using a bright orange texture. I couldn't tell the texturing was working originally because texture is being mixed with an extremely dark shade of grey. Is there any way to brighten this? Also, feel free to provide your first comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Done - added as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Grainy" just looks like you are rendering multiple layers of triangles with blending enabled, and some triangles are being dropped for some reason so those areas are lighter than their neighbours.

Hard to tell why without looking at the model (could be the facing test, or the depth test with very out-of-order triangle streams). In general try disabling the facing test, enabling the depth test, and disabling blending

Comment: Eliminating blending certainly removed the graininess, but it also made the object appear darker. Is there a way to brighten it, either by bringing back blending in a different way or using some other method with the texture?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library, so I'll struggle with a specific answer, sorry. In general the color of an object in OpenGL ES 2.x onwards is under the control of a shader program, so an almost arbitrary set of things are possible by changing that program. For OpenGL ES 1.x then you need to fit into the fixed rendering pipeline, so you'll need to add some form of light source, or change the per-vertex material properties of the mesh.